# Text function/object in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This should be simple....but why is this a null value?

```
var cTxt = d3.select("#visualentry").selectAll('p')
    .text('d3here');
    console.log(cTxt.text())
```

Shouldn't it be something...i.e. 'd3here'?
I've tried setting it like this cTxt = cTxt("d3here");
or
cTxt.text(cTxt.text() + "d3here");

Here is the definition of text:

## selection.text([value])

If value is specified, sets the text content to the specified value on all selected elements. otherwise, if value is a function, then the function is evaluated for each selected element (in order), being passed the current datum d and the current index i, with the this context as the current DOM element. The function's return value is then used to set each element's text content. A null value will clear the content.

Comment: Please see https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#text which says "If value is not specified, returns the text content for the first non-null element in the selection. This is generally useful only if you know the selection contains exactly one element." How many `'p'` are you selecting in `#visualentry`

Comment: Just one. <div id="keyentry">
 <div id="visualentry"><p></p></div>
</div>

Comment: I guess I don't know exactly how to append text to a paragraph as text. I know how to append a paragraph. But I want to append text to that particular paragraph ( i know how to do it w JQuery....just trying to use only d3 )

Comment: Works for me...check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JUd4Z/).